# Sugar orm in unit test produced null pointer exception

Tags: android, database, unit-testing, nullpointerexception, sugarorm

What I'm trying to do is implement a unit test, but I need to clear the database before it.

The problem is that sometimes clearing database fails with NullPointerException.

Basicily I call deleteAll method on every DTO I have (for example BusinessUnit.deleteAll(BusinessUnit.class). And sometimes this fail (though not always).

Null pointer originates from SugarRecord's own method:

```
public static <T extends SugarRecord<?>> void deleteAll(Class<T> type) {
    Database db = SugarApp.getSugarContext().getDatabase();
    SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase = db.getDB(); // exception is thrown here
    sqLiteDatabase.delete(getTableName(type), (String)null, (String[])null);
}
```

What could have caused this error?

Comment: Why a vote down? If I have left out any crucial information, please let me know and I'll try to provide it.

Comment: Let the sugarorm start up at first. Therefore add a Thread.sleep(3000) in the setUp() function of the ApplicationTest class that extends from ApplicationTestCase<T>.

Comment: @Lunero that seems to have done the trick, thank you.
You can also post your commen as an answer, so I can accept it, if you wish.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let the sugarorm start up at first. You have first to let start the SugarOrm. This task needs some time. Therefore add the following:

```
public class ApplicationTest extends ApplicationTestCase<Application> {
@Override
public void setUp() throws Exception {
    super.setUp();

    // SugarORM need some time to start up, else tests will fail
    Thread.sleep(3000);
}
```

Comment: This is not an option, you want the tests to run fast. Not wait 3000 ms

Comment: Also for pure unit tests (not depending on android) this doesnt work either.

Comment: I don't know how to get any callback when the database is done in SugarORM.
Don't have tested it yet, but try roboelectric to test it with unit tests, because the sqlite database component depends on android.